# Extra space in mcrypt_encrypt()

Tags: php, encryption, space, mcrypt

```
global $CONFIGURATIONS;
    $salt = $CONFIGURATIONS['SALT'];
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));'
```

the function returns an encrypted string with some spaces... but when I decrypt the string without spaces the decryption returns correct`enter code here` string... what's wrong ?

Comment: Can you give example values for `$salt` and `$text` so that it produces what you describe? Where do you see spaces in the output? `base64_decode` shouldn't return anything with spaces in it, as it uses only letters, numbers and `+/=` signs.

Comment: $text = '123#1#127.0.0.1#abcd#abcd'; and $salt='abcdefgh';

but when the encryt function return the encrypted value there is space before the encrypted string. and even when I decrypt the encrypted string(without spaces) I get the text but spaces before the text.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have spaces before the `<?` or `<?php` tag that causes PHP to emit whitespace before the output? Try to use `var_dump` since that puts quotes (`"`) arount the string so you can see if the space is part of the return value or comes from somewhere else.

Comment: This PHP fiddle uses the salt and text you supplied and doesn't output any spaces: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a2i-rxn

Comment: You mean, what's wrong *besides* using a string as salt, using salt as key, using ECB mode, using an IV in ECB mode and using Rijndael with a block size of 256 instead of AES?